# Single Sign On with NodeJS on Linux Server in Windows domain network

Tags: linux, node.js, windows, active-directory

in the company i work for we've got a lot of windows 20xx servers. 
we're using an active directory domain controller for authentication.
programs like SharePoint or Dynamics CRM 2015 (hosted on IIS of course) don't need a separate input of user credentials when opened in IE. you open it and you're logged in - magic :) i think it's something that only works with IIS?

i'm developing AngularJS applications with a NodeJS backend. NodeJS backend runs on linux machine, AngularJS app is hosted on the same machine by Nginx webserver. everything is in the same network.

is there any way to authenticate a user in my AngularJS app hosted on that linux machine **without** asking him/her for his/her credentials? a working solution that doesn't require IE would be best case.

thank you very much!

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this issue? - I'm dealing with a _similar_-ish issue....